# How to use default values for derived required properties for maven archetype integration tests?

Tags: maven, maven-archetype, integration-testing

For my organization, I am working on a maven archetype.  Things seem to be working and all tests are successful.  As part of the archetype, I'm using derived required properties:

```
<requiredProperty key="package">
    <defaultValue>${groupId}.${artifactId}</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

For my integration tests, in `archetype.properties`, I have to specify a value for `package` or else it fails.  I would like to not specify any value so that I can confirm the default value is correct.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try `package=` with a newline immediately following the '=' by chance?

Comment: I did try that and the error is the same as if I didn't specify anything

Comment: Maybe have a look at the archetype source code to see how it's processing during integration tests? Might give you a clue.

Comment: There is open issue for this ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-574 ). I have voted for this Jira - please do the same if you would like to make this fixed.